# Favicon Issue on Chrome for iPad with Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I have been trying to add a favicon to my website so it is visible on Chrome for iOS.

The favicon works fine on desktop and Android, but the fix I found was to use Base64 code in your `index.html` in place of an ICO file. This fix shows the favicon on an iPhone but not on my iPad.

Been scouring the Internet for any fixes and found none. Any ideas why/potential fixes?

Tried everything from a png to "apple-touch-icon", but the base64 code was all that worked universally.

I expect the favicon to load on my website, but it does not.

Comment: can you share your favicon code that you use for ipad / pc / etc?

Comment: <link href="data:image/x-icon; base64,iVBORw0KGgoA... (reduced to fit character limit) " rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
This line is what I use for the favicon and it works on chrome for desktop/android and even iphone but not on the ipad. Any help would be appreciated!